# Probability of record breaking temperature on Feb 29 vs other days

Tags: probability, statistics

Is there a higher likelihood of breaking a temperature record (as recorded since NOAA started doing so) on Feb 29th than any other given day, simply because there are fewer sample points to be compared against?

The temperature points would still tend to follow the same bell curve, but would the slightly lower resolution (or fewer sample points) increase the odds of a temperature falling outside the limits of existing points?

Comment: It's just a small discussion with a co-worker, and it's made me curious enough to try to find an answer.

Comment: Yes, for essentially the reasons you state.

Comment: How would one calculate the higher likelihood of a record being set on the 29th vs another day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If NOAA has records going back $120$ years (to make up a number) you can imagine that the high temperatures of the last $121$ years are in random order.  That would say the chance this year is higher than any of the earlier years is $\frac 1{121}$.  As there have only been $30$ leap years in that span, the chance of setting a record would be $\frac 1{31}$ by the same reasoning.

This ignores effects like construction, changes in sensor location, changes in sensor calibration, and climate change that might make this year different from the previous sample.  If you think you know how much the mean has changed, you can use the observed variation to get an approximation to the chance of a record this year.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. And yes, I was assuming we ignore all the other factors potentially affecting the outcome, like you mentioned.